# Jenkins Dockerfile - unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile

Tags: jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I'm having the following issue trying to build a project in Jenkins with the "Build inside a Docker container" functionality.

> Started by user UserName LastName
>   Building in workspace /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/app/workspace
>   /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/pierreburgy/sails-app # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/pierreburgy/sails-app
>   /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git --version # timeout=10
>   /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/pierreburgy/sails-app +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
>   /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
>   Checking out Revision a6e83d91be393fd8d597829ce5f84b336af1572b (refs/remotes/origin/master)
>   /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>   /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git checkout -f a6e83d91be393fd8d597829ce5f84b336af1572b
>   /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git rev-list a6e83d91be393fd8d597829ce5f84b336af1572b # timeout=10
>   Build Docker image from ./Dockerfile ...
>   $ /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool/docker/bin/docker build --tag 17e2f7f926ff8a6c7e412defb7c2cb8140761e26 --file Dockerfile /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/app/workspace
>   unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/logs/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
>   FATAL: Failed to build docker image from project Dockerfile
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build docker image from project Dockerfile
>       at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.Docker.buildImage(Docker.java:127)
>       at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.DockerfileImageSelector.prepareDockerImage(DockerfileImageSelector.java:41)
>       at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.DockerBuildWrapper.setUp(DockerBuildWrapper.java:167)
>       at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:156)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
>   Finished: FAILURE
>   ```

Here is the code of the project : https://github.com/pierreburgy/sails-app

Do you have any idea about what could be the issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get it, your Dockerfile just has `FROM node` and a `echo xxx` can you elaborate? Show the commands you launched?

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub project you're referencing does not have a Dockerfile that actually installs sails. Here's the actual content of the Dockerfile in the project you mentioned.

```
   FROM node
   RUN echo 'we are running some # of cool things'
```

Here's another project that you can check out: https://github.com/artificialio/docker-sails